# Anchor image over the center page where the table lines cross without media queries

Tags: css, image, html-table, responsive

https://jsfiddle.net/ze5k4cqb/
How can I override the center of the page with an image where the table lines cross covering them? It can be done without media queries? With media queries, so with percentage for margins, like this

```
        -webkit-margin-end: -15%;
        -webkit-margin-before: -6%;
        left: 40%;
        top: 40%;
        right: 40%;
```

it fails with different resolution settings.
Exist a trick to do that without 3000 lines of media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool animations on hover. All I can say is that `transform: translate` is your friend. You had some weird negative margin so I had to take that into account with the calc function within the translate.

I also added `pointer-events: none` so you can trigger the quadrant animations even if you hover over `.logo-div`.

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.logo-div {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 15px), -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me but logo is not at center cause div parent dimension and it's blocked like when I try to align center. How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: I solved using mx-auto bootstrap class in parent img div.

Comment: I had to register to fork your fiddle, otherwise I would had linked to my solution. The `#container` div should have `position:relative` to restrict any absolute elements, namely `.logo-div`, to go outside of the container. I updated my answer accordingly.